# How do I make .R files double clickable in ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, executable

I have a .R code which I want to make it double clickable so that the users I share it to don't have to install IDE like RStudio and open the code there then selecting all then clicking run. I have multiple .R files in which I want to do this. One of them is working because it's all background calculations and nothing needs to be displayed. I achieved it by using #!/usr/bin/Rscript in the beginning of the .R code and making the file as executable. That is working.
In another .R file I have file.choose() in the code and code is not getting executed because of it as it is a GUI thing and opening in terminal is not possible I'm guessing.
When I run the same code in RStudio everything works perfectly, but when I try to make it executable it is not working in ubuntu.
Kindly help me!

Comment: use `tcltk::tk_choose.files()`instead